# MySQL String comparison Examples

Tags: mysql, collate

[MySQL Example:](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.1-en/string-comparison-functions.html)

```
SELECT 'ä' = 'ae' COLLATE latin1_german2_ci;
```

Returns 0 and not 1 like in the example:

My variables look like this (after some configuration):
- 'character_set_client',     'latin1'

- 'character_set_connection', 'latin1'
- 'character_set_database',   'latin1'
- 'character_set_filesystem', 'latin1'
- 'character_set_results',    'latin1'
- 'character_set_server',     'latin1'
- 'character_set_system',      'utf8'
- 'character_sets_dir',       'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\share\charsets\'

I think there is an error.
I remember that

- character_set_filesystem was 'binary'
- and the others were 'utf8'.

But this configuration, i get an error that latin1_german2_ci is not suitable with uft8.
So i tried to configured that a simple query like this works:

```
Select * 
from dubletten
where name="Flöss" collate latin1_german2_ci;
```

Before it doesnt, now returns only matches with "Flöss" and not "Floess".

Some idea?

Thanks!

Comment: When you are using UTF-8, you should use collations `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci` – both of those treat German umlauts as equal to their non-umlauted counterparts (with the difference between the two being how `ß` is compared.) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html

Comment: How do you use a query to do this? I already tried to use utf8_unicode_ci, its case insensitive, an works well for ß and ss. But it doesnt work for umlauts. That means if i searched for "Flöss", i dont get Floess, or when i searched FlÖss, i dont get Floess.